# Getting from Düsseldorf airport to the city centre

Tags: public-transport, germany, airport-transfer, dusseldorf, dus

I'm going to be flying into Düsseldorf airport mid-morning, and I'll need to get into the city centre. Is there an option that's fairly quick and not too expensive?

Also, if the best option looks to be public transport, is there a good trip planner I can use to check timetables/options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [Website of Deutsche Bahn](http://bahn.de) you can check the trains. There are about 350 trains a day, so you won't have to wait a lot.

But notice that there are 2 train stations at the airport: one for S-Bahn line 11 ([Bahnhof *Düsseldorf Flughafen Terminal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%BCsseldorf_Airport_Terminal_station)) and another for all the other trains ([Bahnhof *Düsseldorf Flughafen*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%BCsseldorf_Airport_station)).

A single ticket costs 2.40 `EUR`, a daily ticket - 5.70 `EUR`(for S/RB/RE/ERB. IC/ICE-trains are much more expensive and not recommended for such a short distance).
With the train it takes between 5 and 12 minutes to the [*Düsseldorf Central Station*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%BCsseldorf_Central_Station), so I think it's the best option

Comment: This answer would be even better if you mentioned how long the train trip typically takes and how much it costs...

Comment: Yes, you're right, I edited my answer